# A simple drawing program

Tags: javascript, drawing

I need to draw circle and rectangular on a picture on webpage,

For this, I found out some programs and open source projects, like [Zwibbler](http://zwibbler.com), [Literally Canvas](http://literallycanvas.com)

However, they are lack of some features

I need to take the coordinates of the drawn circles and rectangulars

I couldn't find any application for this operation.

If you know some and comment I would be glad

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thank you for those who voted down. It is okey even if you vote down, but better to comment and give some advices.

Comment: Looks like you didn't checked the documentation of the Zwibbler API properly.. See my answer in one min

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this code, paste in a html file, run with your browser, and see what happens, I am not going to explain it, please take a look at the [documentation of Zwibbler](http://zwibbler.com/docs), everything what you see here is taken from there.

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src="http://zwibbler.com/zwibbler-demo.js"></script>
  <div id="zwibbler1" style="width:800px;height:500px"></div>
  <script>
     var ctx = Zwibbler.create("zwibbler1", {});
     ctx.on('document-changed', function() {
       var firstSelectedNode = ctx.getSelectedNodes()[0];
       if (!firstSelectedNode) return;

       var bounds = ctx.getNodeRectangle(firstSelectedNode)
       document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = `x: ${bounds.x}, y: ${bounds.y}`
     });
  </script>
  <br>
  <h1>Position of current NODE: <span id="position"><span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It has e big "DEMO" background though